# KeyError Dictionary Conversion Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a program that converts money from one type of currency to another. So far this is my code:

```
def read_exchange_rates(exchange_file_name):
    #reads file with exchange rates formatted like USD,1. Each line is a 3 letter currency code and a float to convert it to USD. 
    f=open(exchange_file_name,"r")
    answer={}
    for line in f:
        k, v = line.split(",")
        answer[k] = float(v)
    return answer
    f.close()
    pass
class Money:

    exchange_rates = read_exchange_rates(rate_file)
    #calls previously defined function to read file with exchange rates
    def __init__ (self, monamount, code):
        self.monamount=monamount
        self.code=code
    def to(self, othercode):
        i = self.monamount/self.exchange_rates[self.code]
        j = i*self.exchange_rates[self.othercode]
        return othercode+str(j)
```

It should return the converted amount along with it's currency code (othercode) but instead it returns a KeyError. If I type

```
a=Money(650,'USD')
b=a.to('GBP')
```

it should return GBP somenumber. This is the error. Thank you!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#126>", line 1, in <module>
    b=a.to('GBP')
  File "<pyshell#124>", line 9, in to
    i = self.monamount/self.exchange_rates[self.code]
KeyError: 'USD'
```

Comment: Well your exchange rates apparently do not contain `USD`...

Comment: Can you share part of your exchange rate file (with the `USD` key)?

Comment: ADF,5.8524
ADP,148.448
AED,3.6731
AFN,64.31
ALL,127.24
AMD,473.2
ANG,1.82
AOA,135.976
AON,135.976
ARS,9.4448
ATS,12.2768
AUD,1.419
AWG,1.81
AZM,3926
AZN,1.0488
BAM,1.7447
BBD,2
BDT,79.482
BEF,35.9908
BGN,1.7513
BHD,0.3775
BIF,1554
BMD,1
BND,1.4567
BOB,7.0905
BRL,3.9375
BSD,1.0062
BTN,65.372
BWP,10.726
BYR,17781
BZD,2.0401
CAD,1.3155
and so on. USD,1 is in there. Each is a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your file contains 'USD' key?

Here is a slightly modified and simplified code (so I didn't have to create an exchange file):

```
def read_exchange_rates():
    answer={}
    answer['USD'] = 1
    answer['GBP'] = 0.76
    return answer

class Money:
    exchange_rates = read_exchange_rates()
    def __init__ (self, monamount, code):
        self.monamount = monamount
        self.code = code

    def to(self, othercode):
        i = self.monamount/self.exchange_rates[self.code]
        j = i*self.exchange_rates[othercode]
        return othercode + str(j)

a = Money(650,'USD')
b = a.to('GBP')
print(b)
```

This prints out `GBP494.0`.

Comment: It definitely does contain it. One line is USD,1

Comment: I ran your initial code with a sample file (except I added a line for USD,1 since that list was incomplete) and it runs perfectly. As previously, I changed `self.othercode` to just `othercode` in `j = i*self.exchange_rates[othercode]` though that shouldn't be the cause of your error. P.S: other currencies work perfectly too.

Comment: Thank you. I believe the error is in the code I have to read the file, as if I type print(Money.exchange_rates) it returns {}.